# Unknown Property on class

Tags: javafx

i am having an issue of implementing embedded class in table control tiwulfx,It gives an error`"UNKNOWN PROPERTY ON CLASS"`..Thanks in advance,I have an embedded class ,i am  using tiwulfx table Control,whenever i use textcolumn tag it gives an error

[image]

Comment: I think the "unknown property on class" error is being caused by the use of the textcolumn tag, although your stack trace states: "NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'City' on class 'class Model.Broker'" so maybe that's the issue."

Comment: well i want to show the data from another class into the other table class.what can you  suggest can be done.

Comment: Due to the limited amount of information provided by your question, my suggestions would be nothing more than guesses. Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Then make necessary edits to your question.

Comment: @SheikhMoizIrfan Unless you show us some code, it will be really difficult to suggest things.